# Problem with loading assembly when running NUnit (FileNotFoundException)

Tags: nunit, process.start

Recently, I've been using Selenium to record a few simple tests. Although Selenium tests are initially stored as html files, the program allows you to export the test cases in a variety of languages (in this case, I'm using C#).

I downloaded NUnit to use as my testing framework -- I can then load a particular exported C# file into NUnit as a project.

I also created a simple web app where I can click a button to launch NUnit and run a few tests. The problem is, I keep getting this error message:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : File or assembly name nunit.core, or one of its dependencies, was not found.

Once I exit out of this popup, NUnit opens as desired, however, the tests don't load. The source code behind the web app looks like this:

```
public void ButtonClick1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   ProcessStartInfo proc1 = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\selenium-remote-control
1.0.3\\selenium-dotnet-client-driver-1.0.1\\source\\tools\\nunit\\nunit-gui", "TestProject14.dll");

   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(proc1);
}
```

Basically I'm just trying to create a new process which launches the NUnit gui and runs the test. I'm not sure if it can't find the .dll or if it's some other issue.

Any help would be appreciated -- this is my first post, so if I'm missing something completely obvious, I apologize in advance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have

```
using nunit.framework;
```

at the top of your code?

Secondly, have you included an actual reference to the nunit.core dll in your References list? If not, right click "References" and click add reference. Find nunit.core.dll and attach it

Comment: Yes, I included 'using nunit.framework' at the top of my code. I also added a reference to the nunit.core dll -- this is what seems so strange to me. If the reference has been added, why would nunit not be able to find it? Is there somewhere else I need to store the dll as well?

Comment: I had an issue where I was referencing a .dll in a location somewhere other than my project folder. It was solved by actually copying the dll to the project's dependencies folder. See if that changes anything

Comment: I don't see a dependencies folder anywhere in my project folder. Bin, Obj, and Properties are the only folders listed. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 by the way. I've tried storing the .dll in a variety of places (the bin obviously being one of them), but I'm still getting the error. Is there anywhere else you could think to put the .dll?

Comment: I don't see a dependencies folder anywhere in my project folder. Bin, Obj, and Properties are the only folders present. The dll is currently in the bin folder. Wouldn't this be the first place to look for a dll?

Comment: In Solution Explorer, right-click on the project node and click Properties.

In the Project Designer, click the Reference Paths tab.

In the Folder: field, enter the full path to the folder that contains the components.

Click the Add Folder button and click OK.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `WorkingDirectory` of the process to be the NUnit directory. If you do not do that, the working directory will be the one where the application is executing from.

I suggest building up a [`ProcessInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) object with all the details of the process and pass that to the `Process` constructor.

Comment: I tried this, and I got a new error message saying that the file does not exist. I downloaded a newer version of nunit and went through the process again. The gui opens up and attempts to run the test, but for some reason, the remote control window fails to launch. So I'm not sure what the issue is now...